# Is it possible to use fast enumeration on a NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, macos, fast-enumeration

I have the following method (it is an instance method of `ShoppingCart`):

```
- (void) showShoppingCartProducts
 {
   for (Product *eachProduct in products)
    {
      [eachProduct logName]
    }
}
```

I have another method (it is an instance method of `ShoppingCart`):

```
- (void) addProduct: (Product *) newProduct {
    [products objectForKey: newProduct.name];
}
```

It is supposed to iterate through each `(Product *) eachProduct` in `(NSMutableDictionary *) products`.

`logName` does the following (it is an instance method of `Product`):

```
- (void) logName
{
  NSLog(@"%@", self.name);
}
```

Here is my `main()` function

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    ShoppingCart* myShoppingCart = [[ShoppingCart alloc] init];

    Product* myProduct = [[Product alloc] init];

    myProduct.name = @"My Latest Product";

    [myShoppingCart addProduct: myProduct];

    [myShoppingCart showShoppingCartProducts];

    return 0;
}
```

After running the program, it returns 0, but displays nothing.

Is it possible to use fast enumeration on a NSMutableDictionary?

Comment: You never call `showShoppingCartProducts`.

Comment: You’re not using `showShoppingCartProducts` anywhere in your code sample…?

Comment: And you don't show us how Product is declared, or how the array in it is initialized.

Comment: Maybe you just need to bring up the part of the Xcode window where the output goes. Press the middle one of [these three buttons](http://tinyurl.com/jww5nhq) on the top right

Comment: @adam, your link shows some screenshot of an advertisement. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

> NOTE: `[myShoppingCart addProduct: myProduct]` just adds (Product ) *myProduct to a NSMutableDictionary* products in (ShoppingCart *) myShoppingCart

is not adequate explanation. There's no such thing as "just adding an object to an `NSMutableDictionary`". You set a value for a key in dictionaries. Which is `myProduct`, the value or the key? If it's the value, what is the key? If it's the key, what is the value?

To answer the basic question: yes, you can fast enumerate over a dictionary. The ***keys*** are enumerated. If you want the value for each key, you then have to look that up using `-objectForKey:` or the subscripting syntax.

If you think you're adding an object to a dictionary (or any other collection) but then the dictionary (collection) seems to be empty, that's probably because you're dealing with a `nil` pointer and not an actual collection. You neglected to create the collection and store a strong reference to it.

---

You've edited the question to show this method:

```
- (void) addProduct: (Product *) newProduct {
    [products objectForKey: newProduct.name];
}
```

That method does not add the product to the dictionary. `-objectForKey:` **looks up** an object that may already be in the dictionary by its key. It doesn't modify the dictionary. You probably meant to do this:

```
- (void) addProduct: (Product *) newProduct {
    [products setObject:newProduct forKey:newProduct.name];
}
```

---

Given that you succeed in adding `Product` instances to the dictionary and the `name` is an `NSString*`, your enumeration should look like this:

```
for (NSString* name in products)
{
    Product* product = [products objectForKey:name];
    [product logName]
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the error. The value I want to log is the '@property NSString *name' of the 'Products' class instances (in this example, I have one: myProduct)

Comment: So, there was no problem with the NSMutableDictionary, and was just the wrong method? Still, when I use the correct method (that you have given me), the result is the same.

Comment: Are you sure the `products` instance variable (I'm assuming it's an instance variable) is not `nil`? Try logging it. Also, show where it is set. That should probably be within the implementation of `-[ShoppingCart init]`.

Comment: That's a good point. Does @property do that for me as a setter/getter method, or do I have to override it myself? If so, how?

Comment: `@property` declares a property, which usually amounts to declaring (but not defining) accessor methods. `@synthesize`, which can be implicit with modern compilers, can generate (define) the accessor methods and can even generate the instance variable for you (although it would typically have an underscore, such as `_products`; you wouldn't be able to just refer to it as `products`). However, the variable is just a holder for a pointer to an object. It doesn't create the object itself. You need to do that. For example, `_products = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];` in `-init`.

Comment: I suppose you mean the '-init' of ShoppingCart? When I do type in the line you provided, Xcode complains that it should be 'products' rather than '_products'. When I fix the complaint, I end up with 'Thread 1: signal SIGABRT' mark, causing the program to terminate.

Comment: Most likely the fast enumeration is now working and has allowed execution to continue to a different error. For example, the keys of your dictionary are product names, which I assume is a string. However, in your `for` loop, you a) declare the loop variable as a `Product*` which it isn't, and b) call `-logName` on it, which is not a method on an `NSString`. As I said above, fast enumeration on a dictionary enumerates the keys. If you then want the value for a given key, you need to look it up.